# after effects looping for web

Tags: after-effects

im making a video for a website in after effects

Its  a simple under construction page. The video made in after effects effectively has two parts

1. transitions in the text,
2. some minor flicker animation.

I want to keep the flicker animation going for the rest of the time (infinite loop on my page), instead of looping the whole video. How do i Do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a video api like this one: 
http://videojs.com/docs/api/

A simple event would be the solution.

```
var myFunc = function(){
  var myPlayer = this;

if(myPlayer.currentTime == x) {
myPlayer.currentTime(y);
};
myPlayer.addEvent("eventName", myFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is some kind of script (like the one posted by Gijoey above...) You can technically export videos to be "looping" but trusting that keyframing to translate across codecs/browsers is risky. I would convert the vid to something like an FLV / F4V as well. You could wrap it in a SWF if you want to deal with flash, but that's probably unnecessary for this purpose :P